# How do I create a script to remove the body of incoming emails?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a script that I can use with a message rule, to remove the body of incoming emails.  Ideally I would like to leave the first 20 characters intact and delete the rest of the email, but I would settle for deleting the entire contents.

Comment: This is a very strange request.  Do you mean the body of every email or only some?  What is the value of knowing who has sent you an email but not what they wrote?

Comment: For further clarification...

Comment: For further clarification...the email account I need this on, receives attachments from another sender, which is automatically pulled to another application.  The process fails when there is more than 20 characters in the email body.  The issue is the senders signature.  I need it deleted so the extraction can happen.  At this stage that involves manually deleting it.

Comment: Is the problem with every email from this sender or only some?  If only some, can you identify the emails that need their body's deleted?  I think the easiest approach would be a rule that identified the sender and then an a script that deleted the Html body, and reduced the text body to 20 characters.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand how a process that saves attachments can be affected by the size of the body.  I assume this question is because the faulty process is not under your control and cannot easily  be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be simple macro but I have found it impossible to achieve exactly what you requested; however, I have achieved something close.  I have not deleted my diagnostic code so you can experiment yourself and perhaps discover a sequence of statements that I have not tried.

This is the macro that makes the changes:

```
Public Sub ReduceBody(ItemCrnt As Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim ReducedBody As String

  With ItemCrnt

    ' Not all items in Inbox are mail items. It should not be possible for
    ‘ a non-mail-item to reach this macro but check just in case.
    If .Class = olMail Then

      ' I test for a particular subject and a particular sender
      ' Many properties of a mail item can be checked in this way.  Adjust
      ' the If statement as necessary
      If LCase(.Subject) = "attachments" And _
         LCase(.SenderEmailAddress) = "xxxxx.com" Then

        Debug.Print "Html: [" & Replace(Replace(.HtmlBody, vbLf, "{l}"), vbCr, "{r}") & "]"
        Debug.Print "Text: [" & Replace(Replace(.Body, vbLf, "{l}"), vbCr, "{r}") & "]"
        Debug.Print "Format: " & .BodyFormat

        Debug.Assert False   ' Have a look at the initial values of the properties

        ' Save reduced body because clearing the Html body also clears the text body
        ReducedBody = Left$(.Body, 20)
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain   ' Set body format to plain text
        .HtmlBody = "<BODY>" & ReducedBody & "</BODY>"

        Debug.Print "Html: [" & .HtmlBody & "]"
        Debug.Print "Text: [" & .Body & "]"
        Debug.Print "Format: " & .BodyFormat

        Debug.Assert False   ' Have a look at the new values of the properties
        .Close (olDiscard)   ' Delete when the new
        Exit Sub                 ‘ values are as you require

        .Save                        ' Save amended mail item
      End If
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

I believe my comments explain the structure of the macro adequately.

Once the macro has confirmed that the item it has been passed is one it should process, it outputs the current values of the Html body, the text body and the body format to the Immediate Window and uses `Debug.Assert` to stop processing.  Click <kbd>F5</kbd> when you are ready to continue.

The code modifies these three properties, displays their new values and stops again.

I have known for a long time that Outlook will build a text body from an Html body but I had not realised how linked the Html body, the text body and the body format are.  Changing any of them changes the others.  The modification code I have provided, is the best I have been able to create which is:

- Text body = first 20 characters of original text body
- Html body = “” & first 20 characters of original text body & “”
- Body format = Html

When you restart the macro with <kbd>F5</kbd>, the changes will be discarded.  Unless the changes are discarded, they will be saved even if you do not execute the save command.  Keep the discard statements until the values displayed are acceptable.

To test the above macro, I used:

```
Sub TestReduceBody()

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      Call ReduceBody(ItemCrnt)
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

I use a macro like this to test all my new mail-item, processing macros.  Select one or more mail items and then start this macro.  This macro allows me to start with a simple email and, only when that is processed correctly, do I try more complicated emails. I have several email addresses and I sent suitable test emails from a secondary account to my main account.  You will have genuine emails ready to test.  I highly recommend using macros like this.

Once you have amended the first macro to your requirements, set up a rule and link the rule to this macro.  I assume you know how to create a rule, but I can provide instructions if necessary.